# WP7 Silverlight: How do I add two Button to a Border of a WrapPanel

Tags: silverlight, button, border, wrappanel

For a calendar app (silverlight WP7.5), I use wrappanel to contain days (Border with Button as child). Now I would like to add another button inside the Border. So each day will have number and additional info/graphics. Just noticed that Border can contain only 1 child. How do I do with it?

```
Border border = new Border();
Button btn = new Button();
border.Child = btn;
//Button btn_notification = new Button();
// how to add the btn_notification????
CalendarWrapPanel.Children.Add(border);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another Container (Grid, StackPanel, ...) inside your Border.
This examples demostrates it with a StackPanel:

```
Border border = new Border();
Button btn = new Button();
Button btn_notification = new Button();
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Children.Add(btn);
panel.Children.Add(btn_notification);
border.Child = panel;
CalendarWrapPanel.Children.Add(border);
```